# how to disable ssl_verifypeer in webworks?

Tags: ssl, blackberry, ssl-certificate, blackberry-webworks

I am working on a webworks application for BlackBerry and I am getting an SSL Certificate Exception when connecting to a specific site.
Is there a way to disable the ssl check in the code, without showing the exception dialog to the user?

Comment: Do you really want to do that? Users have specific expectations when connecting to secure websites. In some cases a certificate exception may be for some trivial non-threatening reason, but that will not always be true.

Comment: He is talking about application, user have no clue where is connecting to at first place, because he doesn't have access to URL, so it is legit. Problem is AFAIK tehe is no way to disable security exception check.